# Refresh the page if a word found imacros

Tags: imacros

i want imacros to go to a specific page
and search for a word then refresh the page and loop search if word is found else move to next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use javascript scripting. No one will make you a script like this but here is an example.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:sometext";


if(iimPlay(macro)>0)
{
//text is there
//do something 

}
else
{
//text is not there
}
```